# rest_framework_swagger 2.1 configuration: how do you pass the api key?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token, swagger

## The problem

I'm attempting to update Swagger for my Django app which uses Token-based authentication with Django Rest Framework.  I keep getting the following error when I visit the docs page:

```
401 : {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
http://localhost:7000/api/docs/?format=openapi
```

Clearly, it's not passing the API key in the header.  My problem is that I don't
know how to supply it an API Key through settings/environment variables/etc.
Does someone know of a representative example, or can someone tell me what's wrong?

## What I've done so far

- I've read the [documentation for Swagger](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/)
- I've attempted to add `api_key` to the settings in different ways, following
  the basic layout of the documentation:

  ```
  SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
      'LOGIN_URL': 'rest_framework:login',
      'LOGOUT_URL': 'rest_framework:logout',
      'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
      'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
          'basic': {'type': 'apiKey'},
          'api_key': {
              'type': 'apiKey',
              'in': 'header',
              'name': 'Authorization',
          },
      },
  }
  ```

  I've tried putting `"api_key": "<the api key>"` under `SWAGGER_SETTINGS` and
  under `SECURITY_DEFINITIONS`, but it has't worked.
- I've read the python source code for Swagger, but it doesn't directly handle
  tokens.  It does pass the `securityDefinitions` to an `OpenAPICodec`, which
  returns a JSON dump of a swagger object created from those
  `securityDefinitions`.
- I've read some of the [OpenAPI Specifications](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-definitions-object) on
  the `securityDefinitions` object.  In the documentation, it describes a
  "security requirement object" which seems to be what I need.  It describes it
  as

  ```
  {
      "api_key": []
  }
  ```

  But it then says that for authentication types other than oAuth, the array
  value must be an empty array.  So, where do I pass the API Key?
- I've tried searching github for examples.  However, everyone seems to have
  the exact same settings file as I have.  So, is it passed through an 
  environmental variable?
- And, of course, I've searched StackOverFlow.  But most of the questions I've
  found deal with earlier versions of Swagger (mostly 0.3.0).

Any ideas?